# Unable to access /admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links

Tags: drupal

Unable to access /admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links when click from the admin panel menu links. There is no error and give me a blank page. But in localhost there is no problem.
Without this link (/admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links) everything is fine. Please help me............

Answer (score 0):

Blank page = WSOD, ye olde white screen of death. Check your server error logs, you'll find the cause.

Comment: I have checked my server error log and there is no error log entry. Also i delete the all item of watchdog table but still have my problem. I search to google more than four days about this issue but can not find the actual solution. Although i checked google search result few solution but can not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [The White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043), the cause may be listed there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. First i find my error from your link page instruction then i fix my error and my project works correctly. Thanks again..........